# HKAnchoredObjectQuery results handler doesn't fire after initial results

Tags: watchos-2, healthkit

Our fitness app was using three anchored object queries to stream heart rate, active calories and distance; it was working just fine until a few weeks ago when we started optimizing the rest of the app's performance to be more responsive and query samples for past workouts. We believe we've restored the queries back to the way they were before, and we have very similar code but written in Swift for a separate fitness app working fine, but these HKAnchoredObjectQuerys just don't return further results after the initial results are handled (yes, a workout session is active). We're a bit stumped. Can anyone take a look and suggest where we might have gone wrong?

Thank you!

Here's an example of the heart rate query:

```
- (HKQuery*) createHeartRateStreamingQuery: (NSDate *) workoutStartDate {  
    NSPredicate * predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:workoutStartDate endDate:nil options:HKQueryOptionNone];  

    HKQueryAnchor *anchor = HKAnchoredObjectQueryNoAnchor;  
    if (_HRAnchor) {  
        anchor = _HRAnchor;  
    }  

    HKQuantityType * quantityType = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];  

    HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query =  
    [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc]  
     initWithType:quantityType  
     predicate:predicate  
     anchor:anchor  
     limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit  
     resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery * query,  
                      NSArray<HKSample *> * sampleObjects,  
                      NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> * deletedObjects,  
                      HKQueryAnchor * newAnchor,  
                      NSError * error) {  

             if (error) {  
                 NSLog(@"*** %s An error occured while performing the heartrate anchored object query. %@ ***",  
                       __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);  
                 abort();  
             } else {  
                 if (newAnchor) {  
                     _HRAnchor = newAnchor;  
                     NSLog(@"*** %s: %i samples returned for startDate %@ ***", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, sampleObjects.count, workoutStartDate);  
                     for (HKQuantitySample *sample in sampleObjects) {  
                         [self updateHeartRate:sample];  
                     }  

                     for (HKDeletedObject *sample in deletedObjects) {  
//                         [self removeHRSamples: sample]; //not using this for now         
                     }  

                 }  
             }  
     }];  
    return query;  
}  
- (void) updateHeartRate: (HKQuantitySample *) HRSample {  
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, HRSample);  
    [_workoutHRSamplesArray addObject: HRSample];  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to stream samples using an `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`, you must set the `updateHandler` property on the query.  The results handler you provided to the initializer is only intended to run once for the existing samples that match your query.

Comment: Interesting. I will try that. Thanks very much Allan!

Comment: To get the query to provide ongoing results while your app is in the background you need to execute HKHealthStore.enableBackgroundDeliveryForType

Comment: Thanks steve1951. It appears that HKHealthStore.enableBackgroundDeliveryForType is necessary for HKObserverQueries, but not necessary in this case because we are using anchoredObjectQueries (it's not available in watchOS). Appreciate the heads up though!

Comment: It is not necessary to enable background delivery to use HKObserverQuery, but the converse is true (you must use HKObserverQuery when using background delivery).